# How to generate access token for testing with Azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory

We have a spring boot REST API which will be used by mobile client. Azure AD is used for auth. We need to generate access token for initial testing spring boot REST API. What is the recommended option for this?
Basically we need to to generate access token using client credentials and call the REST API end point using the access token. Then on the REST API, validate access token and print the app roles assigned in Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the access token from Azure AD to authenticate and authorize users from Azure AD.

1. First, you need to register both the application mobile client and spring boot applications in your Azure AD. Refer [register your application in the Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).
2. To generate access token using client credentials flow, there would be no user involvement, so your server application needs to create an appRole, and then grant the app Role as an application permission to the client application.
   The administrator must grant the correct application permissions via a consent process to access the application.
3. Configure the application's details registered in Azure AD to your spring boot application.properties file with application id, tenant id, client-secret and scope.
4. Refer [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide#protect-a-resource-serverapi) to configure client application to access a web API using spring boot step by step.